# How can I change the color of the text in the tab of a QTabWidget

Tags: c++, css, qt

I'm not talking about the stuff within the tab, but the tab itself. Aside from it looking weird, I'd like to closely emulate Mac's native look.
Here's a screenshot of some system settings
[image: settings screenshot]

and here's a pic of what I have.

[image]

I've tried

`QTabWidget tabWidget;
tabWidget.setStyleSheet("color: #ffffff");`

but that just changes all the text within the tab widget itself. Any help?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar

Comment: I think you should try something like this:
 QTabBar::tab:selected {
    color: #ffffff;
}

But if you share some more code it's gets much easier reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this way:

```
tabWidget->tabBar()->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:selected {\
                                   color: #00ff00;\
                                   background-color: rgb(0,0,255);\
                               }");
```

or, for only one tab:

```
tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabTextColor(1,Qt::white);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use style Sheet like this:

```
ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(119, 133, 255);");
```

Or use [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html) functions for specific item:

```
ui->tabWidget->item(i,j)->setTextColor(QColor(color));
ui->tabWidget->item(i,j)->setBackgroundColor(QColor(color));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way:

```
QTabWidget tabWidget;
tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:selected { color: #ffffff; }");
```

In my example this works!